# How to choose a path by using matrices?

Tags: matrices, matlab

A taxi driver wants to pickup passenger who is in another city knowing that  there are 3 routes of varying in distance.
How the taxi driver can choose path by using matrices in picture below?

[image: The table]

Comment: what have you tried in answering this question?

Comment: Actually this question have many methods specially in statistical methods, but I need method using only matrices to solve it , I found algorithm called Dijkstra algorithm this algorithm using matrices but its not helpful for my question that my thought.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are optimizing. Before you read/google more about methods and solutions, you have to first figure out what is your actual quesiton.  When it comes to consultation, some time are really spent on discussion to find out the question of interest.

If you are optimizing fuel cost, look at that column, pick the smallest fuel cost. Similarly for distance.

I see that there is also the expected pick up time as well, in that case, you have to talk to the taxi driver, is there a time that he needs to be there by? Is there an incentive to be there early? What is the trade off in terms of time and monetory value? Is it plausible to model it in terms of linear combination?  It really depends on the context.